# Migrating to a new version of realm?

Tags: android, realm

In android I have realm version 0.86. I tried to upgrade to 1.1.1, but afterwards It threw an error saying I needed a realm migration. Does anyone know how to migrate from one version to another? Is there a safer version I can upgrade to that would be easier to implement? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have migration examples here, that you can use to get you started: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java

Migrations in general are documented here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

An easy solution for the use case where you use Realm as a caching mechanism for network requests. Just add `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` to your RealmConfiguration: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded--

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade your Realm DB to newer version to 1.0.0+ from any older version then this
If we by default run the app then we got Migration error. However by using Migration define as below we can solve this.

Define Realm app instance inside Application class as below :

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

    VolleyHelper.init(this);

    // The Realm file will be located in Context.getFilesDir() with name "default.realm"
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .migration(new MyMigration())
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
}}
```

If you don't do any change in database structure and only upgrade the Realm version then Define Migration class as below. If you do any database structure change then you have to define that under MyMigration class. You can get more migration information from here [Realm Migration](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations)

```
public class MyMigration implements RealmMigration {
@Override
public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

}}
```

Comment: He needs to migrate because `@PrimaryKey` became nullable in 0.89.0

Answer (score 0):

Others have already linked example migrations and [the docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations), so I'll just tell you that you're running into the [breaking change in 0.89.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

```
@PrimaryKey field value can now be null for String, Byte, Short, Integer, and Long types. 
Older Realms should be migrated, using RealmObjectSchema.setNullable(), 
or by adding the @Required annotation. (#2515).
```

So if you want to avoid using a migration in this case, you just have to specify `@Required` on your `@PrimaryKey` fields.